# Cannot get value out of the function, even though I have a very similar one that works. - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

So this first one does NOT work. I am getting a snapshot and iterating through to build a list of values, I then want to take those values to use elsewhere. Any ideas? The second one is almost identical and it works.

```
getAllFavoriteRecipes(RecipeNotifier recipeNotifier, favoriteIDs) async {
  var uid = (await AuthServices().getCurrentUser());
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> favorites =
  Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).snapshots();
  List _favorites = [];
  favorites.forEach((item) {
    var favoriteItem = item.data['favorites'];
    _favorites.add(favoriteItem);
    print('_favorites: $_favorites'); //<<This does print correctly>>>
  });
  List favoriteIDs2 = _favorites;
  print('Hello: $_favorites'); //<<<<<does NOT print correctly>>>>>
  print('Test: $favoriteIDs2'); //<<<<<does NOT print correctly>>>>>

  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('recipes')
      .where('recipeID', whereIn: favoriteIDs2)
      .getDocuments();
  List<RecipeList> _recipes = [];
  snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
    RecipeList recipe = RecipeList.fromMap(document.data);
    _recipes.add(recipe);
  });
  recipeNotifier.recipeList = _recipes;
}
```

This one prints correctly, although they are doing the same thing:

```
QuerySnapshot featured =
      await Firestore.instance.collection('featured').getDocuments();
  List _featured = [];
  featured.documents.forEach((document) {
    var featuredItem = document.data['recipeID'];
    _featured.add(featuredItem);
  });

  List featuredIDs = _featured;
  print(featuredIDs);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [forEach()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Stream/forEach.html) returns a Future, which you could `await`, just like you are with the Future returned by [getDocuments()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html).

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> favorites =
      Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).snapshots();
  List _favorites = [];
  await favorites.forEach((item) {
    var favoriteItem = item.data['favorites'];
    _favorites.add(favoriteItem);
    //print('_favorites: $_favorites');
  });

  print('Hello: $_favorites'); //<<<<<does NOT print correctly>>>>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not make any difference. In the first print it works. In the second it shows an empty List.